# Cannot edit my document in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe

I am typing and creating a tex file using Latexila (which I *think* is compiling via pdftex) and am asking a few friends to help edit this doc. These friends, however, are not conversant with tex, and thus wish to simply use Adobe Reader to edit the doc. But, when they attempt to do so, they are unable to because they say that Reader will not let them do so because the doc is password protected or something to the like. How can I change this? I was not even aware I was putting any password on the doc, and have tried (in Natilus) changing said doc to read and write by anyone, but to no avail. BTW, I am using the current version of Latexila (2.6.2) on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: As far as I know you have to buy the full version of Adobe Acrobat to edit the document rather than adding annotations/comments.

Comment: Well when I open Reader, I see the ability to add 'sticky-notes' and other edits, but even when I try on this particular doc; I am unable to do so because of some kind of password-protection or something similar.

Comment: @MichaelDykes pdfTeX doesn't add any passwords to PDFs it creates. However, Adobe Reader has over the years had restrictions on what it will and will not allow in terms of changes: Adobe's business model after all is based around selling full copies of the software. At the very least we'll need some example of your input (I guess plus pdfTeX version) and the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: If you and your friends join Mendeley (http://www.mendeley.com/) you can post your pdf there and they can comment. Then you can make changes to your `TeX` source, recompile and repost.

Comment: @JosephWright Here is part of my code:                    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\author{MD}
\title{Weekday Prayers}


\begin{document}                                         In the Name of the Father, ...            \end{document}                                           When I open Reader and go to 'tools' then 'customize toolbars' then 'more tools' all options have a star with the indication saying they are only available when doc rights are enabled.

Comment: @EthanBolker I guess that might be an option. I was really looking for a way I could send the pdf via email to them and have them put stickies and highlight, underline, delete, etc the pdf file then send it back to me and let me make appropriate changes then recompile and begin again. :)

Comment: @JosephWright I must apologize for the clutter, I am still having trouble remembering how to indicate code in replies, and still (as you can see) am forgetting how to do this. My apologies sir.

Comment: @MichaelDykes --- It's usually best not to put code in comments; you can edit your question and insert the code there. Also, what version of Adobe Reader are you using?

Comment: @IanThompson Okay, that makes sense about not putting comments into responses; and I am using Reader v 9.

Comment: @MichaelDykes --- I tried your example with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` and with `pdflatex`. In both cases I was able to insert stickies and highlights using Reader 10.1.6 (on a Mac). Maybe you just need to update Adobe Reader.

Comment: Mendeley is probably better than sending copies in email. You'd get all your stickies in the same file, and people could see each others' comments.

Comment: I am unaware of a Reader 10 download for Ubuntu 13.04 at the moment, and I ***really*** would rather not [unless absolutely necessary] run it under Wine. And @EthanBolker I am trying to avoid both of my parties having to download additional software as one of them is older and does not have as much patience for 'new' things/software (even rather simple things) and I would rather keep it as simple as possible here. :)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a version issue. With Adobe Reader X (and presumably XI) commenting is enabled by default. However, the feature is disabled in Reader 9 unless enabled by Acrobat. I tried a few hacks, but was unable to determine exactly what Acrobat does to a pdf to enable commenting.

There is [a discussion of alternative software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17031/is-there-a-way-to-enable-commenting-adobe-pdf) for annotating pdfs on askubuntu, but if your friends are using Mac OS or Windows they just need to update Adobe Reader.

Comment: To enable commenting of a PDF in Adobe Reader the PDF has to be digitally signed by Adobe, which is only possible with software by Adobe (Acrobat et.al.); see [Adobe LiveCycle Reader Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_LiveCycle_Reader_Extensions).

Answer (score 1):

From [Adobe reader FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/faq.html)

> Can I edit a PDF file using Reader?
>
> No. You cannot make permanent changes to PDF files using Reader. To edit PDF files, purchase Acrobat software.

Comment: I do not need permanent changes, just the ability for my friends to highlight, underline, etc suggestions to the document using Reader. I do remember (not sure which document or if I still even have the document on my hard drive anymore) I created a doc using latex once and the resulting pdf file my friend *could* underline, higlight etc using Reader. That is all I am trying to accomplish here again. Thanks.